# End AfterSave event from different macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that, upon save, asks the user if the file they are working is the final version. If it is, I would like to save a copy of that file in a different destination. It also creates an indicator with the username and date saved of the final copy so that if a user tries to create ANOTHER final copy, it asks them if they would like to overwrite the version created by [username] on [date].

I decided to use AfterSave as opposed to BeforeSave, as I would like the user to have the option of choosing between Save and SaveAs before the macro runs.

The issue that I am having is that if the user indicates that it is the final version, a copy is saved, triggering the AfterSave event. Is there a line of code I can add that would stop the AfterSave event after the file copy is saved?

Here is my current code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    If Success Then
        Call YesNoMessageBox
    End If
End Sub

'Saves copy of tool if final version
Sub YesNoMessageBox()

Dim Answer1 As String
Dim MyNote1 As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog
Dim MyYear
Dim FilePath
Dim Answer2 As String
Dim MyNote2 As String

MyNote1 = "Is this the FINAL version?"

'Display MessageBox
Answer1 = MsgBox(MyNote1, vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "???")

If Answer1 = vbYes Then
    If Not Worksheets("Data Input").Range("M2") = vbNullString Then
        MyNote2 = "There is already a version saved by " & Worksheets("Data Input").Range("M2") & " on " & Worksheets("Data Input").Range("M3") & "." & vbNewLine & "Would you like to overwrite it?"
        Answer2 = MsgBox(MyNote2, vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "???")
        If Answer2 = vbYes Then
            strUName = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
            Worksheets("Data Input").Range("M2") = strUName
            Worksheets("Data Input").Range("M3") = Date

            'Saves copy of tool in [folder name] folder
            MyYear = Year(Worksheets("Data Input").Range("D13"))
            ThisWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:="G:\[file path]" & Worksheets("Data Input").Range("D9") & " - " & Worksheets("Data Input").Range("D7") & " " & MyYear & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

           MsgBox "Copy of tool saved in" & Application.ThisWorkbook.Path

        End If
    Else
        strUName = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
        Worksheets("Data Input").Range("M2") = strUName
        Worksheets("Data Input").Range("M3") = Date

        'Saves copy of tool in [folder name]folder
        MyYear = Year(Worksheets("Data Input").Range("D13"))
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:="G:\[File Path]\" & Worksheets("Data Input").Range("D9") & " - " & Worksheets("Data Input").Range("D7") & " " & MyYear & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

        MsgBox "Copy of tool saved in" & Application.ThisWorkbook.Path

    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't really see the business logic of the problem and I find your code quite unstructured. What got to understand is that you want that in the second save operation the AfterSave event is not called. I can recommend two options: either disable/enable events (Application.EnableEvents = False/True) before or after ThisWorkbook.SaveAs, or use a status variable: before/after ThisWorkbook.SaveAs flip a Boolean, and execute the code in the eventhandler depending on this variable.

Comment: I apologize for the obscurity of my question and structure of my code. I wasn't kidding when I said I was a beginner.

Comment: Clarifying business logic: The issue is that we need users to save final versions of this file into a separate directory so that we can run a macro that grabs data from it. Often they forget to copy the final and we have to contact the user.

As for the structure of my code, do you have any suggestions or tips that I can implement? 

Finally, I would like to thank you for the suggestion to disable/enable the event. It worked. I knew there had to be a solution like that, but I wasn't sure of the language to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable events before the `SaveAs` but don't forget to enable again after:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False 
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:="G:\[File Path]\" & Worksheets("Data Input").Range("D9") & " - " & Worksheets("Data Input").Range("D7") & " " & MyYear & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
Application.EnableEvents = True
```